# Remove option from generic class view in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I just started learning Django this week and I'm trying to figure out how I can remove an option from a select menu being rendered in a class based view. The dropdown is for a Foreign Key field that links to my users table.

The functionality here is that I do not want the current user logged into show up on that list (basically I don't want someone to be able to select themself). How can I go about doing this?

View:

```
class TransferCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Transfer
    template_name = 'points/transfer_form.html'
    fields = ['receiver', 'message', 'amount']
```

Model:

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, 
                 on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    amount = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(1000)],
        null=False)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Basically, I don't want the person who is the sender (which i was going to set in the code in a form_valid() function) to be an option for 'receiver' in the template when it renders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `get_form` method of the `CreateView` and change the queryset of that field, something like this:

```
class TransferCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Transfer
    template_name = 'points/transfer_form.html'
    fields = ['receiver', 'message', 'amount']

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['receiver'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(id=self.request.user.id)
        return form
```

Comment: IDE said I needed different arguments - get_form(self, *args, **kwargs) - but other than that this worked great, thanks so much!